# Get User/Group Permissions for List using javascript(ecmascript)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom

I am trying to use the javascript object model to retrieve a list of users/groups for a list and their permissions at the list level. So far I have this which returns a member object but I cant get any information about the member. When I try to use rAssignment.get_member().get_id(), or rAssignment.get_member().get_title() I get an error.

```
        //Get List Permissions
        function getListPerms() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var siteColl = clientContext.get_site();
            var site = clientContext.get_web();
            listSecurableObject = site.get_lists().getByTitle($("[name='ListSlct']").val());
            listRoleAssignments = listSecurableObject.get_roleAssignments();
            clientContext.load(listRoleAssignments);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.getListPerms_onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.getListPerms_onQueryFailed));
       }
       function getListPerms_onQuerySucceeded() {
            var listPerms="";
            listPerms += '<table border="1">';
            listPerms += '<tr>';
            listPerms += '<td align="center">ID</td>';
            listPerms += '</tr>';
            var listPermsEnumerator =  this.listRoleAssignments.getEnumerator();
            while (listPermsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var rAssignment = listPermsEnumerator.get_current();
                listPerms += '<tr>';
                listPerms += '<td align="center">' + rAssignment.get_member() +  '</td>';
                listPerms += '</tr>';
            }
            listPerms += '</table>';
            document.getElementById('listPermsTable').innerHTML = listPerms;
       }
       function getListPerms_onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
           alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
       }
```

Comment: It returns me the error "Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested." ... Did you search on Google? Because it gave me that thread: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30828/the-property-or-field-has-not-been-initialized-it-has-not-been-requested-or-the

Comment: Yes I did, I tried requesting the ID and Title explicitly and it still threw the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your clientContext.load() function call as follows:

```
clientContext.load(listSecurableObject, 'Include(RoleAssignments, RoleAssignments.Include(Member))');
```

Now in the getListPerms_onSucceeded() method you ought to be able to enumerate through listSecurableObject.get_roleAssignments() and get the members similar to how you're already doing it (although you'll probably want to use rAssignment.get_member().get_loginName() ).