# ERROR: The collection has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am querying the contents of the Managed Metadata using the code below. I am encountering an error

> The collection has not been initialized

when I am in the `var level2TermsEnum = level2Terms.getEnumerator();`

I have read that this is because of the deferred and promise of JavaScript and I can't seem to understand it. Maybe you could help me shed some light on here.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";

        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",

        function () {

            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {

                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function () {

                    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);

                    //Term Stores
                    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
                    //Term Store under which to create the group.
                    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Managed Metadata Service");
                    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("7b6ee52v-3709-4181-a14d-b953f2ad0aad");
                    //Call your code here.

                    GetTermsFromTaxonomyStore();
                });

            });

        });

        var json = "";
        function GetTermsFromTaxonomyStore() {

            //Current Context
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            //Current Taxonomy Session
            var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
            var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
            //Term Store under which to create the term.
            //var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
            var termStore = termStores.getByName("Managed Metadata Service");
            //Pass ID of the Meetings Term Set
            var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("7b6ee52v-3709-4181-a14d-b953f2ad0aad");
            var terms = termSet.get_terms();
            context.load(terms);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var level1Terms = terms.getEnumerator();
                while (level1Terms.moveNext()) { //iterate thru Level1
                    var level1 = level1Terms.get_current();
                    if (level1.get_termsCount() > 0) { //check if Level1 has child
                        var level2Terms = level1.get_terms(); //get level2 terms of level 1 term
                        **var level2TermsEnum = level2Terms.getEnumerator();**
                        while (level2TermsEnum.moveNext())
                        {
                            var level2Term = level2TermsEnum.get_current();
                            var level2TermName = level2Term.get_name();
                            termsList += '"Level1":"' + level2Term.get_name() + '","Level2":"' + level2TermName + '"';
                        }

                    }
                    //console.log(currentTerm.get_name());
                }
                alert(termsList);

            }, function (sender, args) {
                console.log(args.get_message());
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the client object model returns a collection of objects for you, if each of those objects has its own sub-collections, they won't be initialized unless you explicitly ask for them to be loaded.

Similar to the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935101/get-user-group-permissions-for-list-using-javascriptecmascript/18346307#18346307), you should be able to update your call to `context.load()` with an additional parameter telling it what to load.

I believe something like the below code will work, but I haven't tested it:

```
context.load(terms,"Include(Name,Terms,Terms.Include(Name))");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but where can I get the list of objects/parameters to be loaded?

Comment: @Aventus `terms` is a collection of Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Term objects, so you can find its list of member properties here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.term_members.aspx